# Class variables not in the scope of class functions

Tags: ruby

I have the following bit of code:

```
class Test {
  @s = 'Bob'

  def print_bob
    p @s
  end
end
```

When I try to call `print_bob`, it prints `nil`. Why is this? I understood class variables are visible from anywhere in a class?

Comment: BTW, you can assign default values for your instance variables in `Test#initialize`, see http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/doc/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Instance+Variables

Comment: Eden, you need to delete `{`.  No reply, plz--I'll delete this comment once you've seen it.

Comment: Eden, the answers explain that `@s` is a class instance variable.  In fact, you could have an instance variable (defined in `initialize`, say) with the same name (`@s`) and they would co-exist no differently than would `@night` and `@day`.  If you needed the value of the class instance variable in your `print_bob` method, replace `p @s` with `p self.class.instance_variable_get(:@s)
`.  Then `Test.new.print_bob #=> "Bob"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@s` is an *class instance variable*, not the instance variable of the instances of the `Test` class. `print_bob` is an instance method. As you are not defining those instance variables, while you are creating the instances of `Test`, thus when you will call the method `print_bob` on the instances of `Test`, you will get `nil`. Remember - *instance and class variables*, if you attempt to use them before defining, they will return *nil*.

Look the below code:

```
class Test 
  @s = 'Bob'

  def print_bob
    p @s
  end
end

test = Test.new
# Now see, here no instance variables are listed, for instance test. Because you did
# not create any.
test.instance_variables # => []
# you can see, @s is listed in the method call, because has been defined when the
# class has been created.
Test.instance_variables # => [:@s]
```

Comment: I see. This is exactly what I've been looking for. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

`@s` is instance variable definition, not a class variable. So in the class body, defining `@s` defines class intance variable, but if you try to refer it in method body, you refer "regular" instance variable, which is unset.

Class variables are defined with `@@`, so this should work as you expect:

```
class Test {
  @@s = 'Bob'

  def print_bob
    p @@s
  end
end
```